# UITableView: cell.textLabel.text error: [__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]

Tags: nsstring, nsarray, tableview, nsmanagedobject

I'm downloading an NSManagedObject.  Assigning an NSString to valueForKey@"username" of that object. Next, I assign that string to a cell.textLabel.text in UITableView and I'm getting an exception.

The following is the code thats throwing an exception:

```
-(NSString *)fetchUserName
{
    if ([fetchedUserNameObject objectAtIndex:0]!= NULL)
    {
        recipientUser = (User*)(fetchedUserNameObject);
        NSString *userName = (NSString*)[recipientUser  valueForKey:@"username"];            
        return userName;
    }
 }
```

.....

```
      NSString *recipientUserName = [self fetchUserName]
```

......

```
- (IBAction)reviewButtonPressed:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Recipient UserName from Review Button %@", recipientUserName);

    PDReviewVC *modalVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"pdReview"];
    UINavigationController *navBar=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:modalVC];

    modalVC.recipientUserName= self.recipientUserName;
    [self presentViewController:navBar animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

**Log**

```
2013-08-30 11:51:49.393 Time[1188:c07] Recipient UserName from Review Button (
        iphone3gs
    )
```

**Now in PDReviewVC:**

.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * recipientUserName;
```

.m

```
@synthesize recipientUserName;
```

...
//cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
if (indexPath.section == 0)
{
    cell.textLabel.text = recipientUserName;
}
```

I get the following error on  cell.textLabel.text = recipientUserName;:

```
2013-08-30 11:51:54.679 Time[1188:c07] -[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb889390
2013-08-30 11:53:53.303 Time[1188:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb889390'
*** First throw call stack:
```

**UPDATE**

NSLog for the following code:

```
if ([fetchedUserNameObject objectAtIndex:0]!= NULL)
{
    recipientUser = (User*)(fetchedUserNameObject);
    NSLog(@"User %@", recipientUser);
    NSString *userName = (NSString*)[recipientUser valueForKey:@"username"];
    NSLog (@"userName from fetchUserName: %@", userName);
    NSLog(@"%@", userName);

    return userName;

}
else return NULL;
```

NSLog:

```
2013-08-30 12:36:29.495 Time[1341:c07] User (
    "<User: 0xa55cd60> (entity: User; id: 0xa5a0ae0 <x-coredata://3B273CFB-1CAA-4FA0-95DC-BA9420219380-1341-000007F42366B21A/User/piphone3gs> ; data: <fault>)"
)
2013-08-30 12:36:29.496 Time[1341:c07] userName from fetchUserName: (
    iphone3gs
)
2013-08-30 12:36:29.496 Time[1341:c07] (
    iphone3gs
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is right in your error message. :-)

It's telling you that the object you think is of type `NSString` is really `NSArray`. Thus, NSArray does not respond to any method called `isEqualToString`.

In your fetchUserName method you are casting an object as NSString and returning it, but apparently you are getting an NSArray here. When you set this object to your label's text property, something goes on behind the scenes to ask if the current string property is equal to the one you're trying to set. Then, error.

Try placing this line before you `return` in the fetchUserName method:

```
NSLog(@"%@",username);
return username;
```

Then modify your question with the console results of this NSLog() and we can help you figure out what is inside the array.

Ok, before you return the username object, do this:

```
NSString *username;
id object = [recipient valueForKey:@"username"];
if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    username = (NSString *)object;
    return username;
} else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    NSArray *returnedArray = (NSArray *)object;
    if (returnedArray.count > 0) {
        id arrayMember = [returnedArray objectAtIndex:0];
        if ([arrayMember isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
            username = (NSString *)arrayMember;
            return username;
        }
    }
}
return nil;
```

Comment: Thanks.  Modified the question with Update.

Comment: It looks like iPhone3GS is the only member of the array. Look at my updated answer in a moment

Comment: Updated the answer. This should be a working solution. I want to make sure you understand what it is and why it works. This answer only accounts for finding the very first object in the returned array. In case the first object is not an NSString, it will then fail. If this is ever the case you'll need to iterate the array contents using fast enumeration ( a `for()` loop) to find every object inside the array.

Comment: Got it.  Makes sense.  I suspected I would have to do something to that effect.  I'm curious as to why the valueForKey=@"username" is being returned as an array.  When an object is created, username is an NSString.  Thank you again!

Comment: Not sure. I don't work with CoreData very much. The entity that gets returned is a User object, right? For whatever case, your model is generating an NSArray and assigning it to the User object at the username property. Whatever the code is for generating your User objects, i'd start there. Just like you were easily assigning NSArray to something that should be a string, just as easily up the chain it's happening behind the scenes

Answer (score 1):

You are casting `[recipientUser valueForKey:@"username"]` as an `NSString` to get your code to work, when it is in fact returning an `NSArray`. Remove the cast `(NSString*)` and get the code working so you are in fact pulling a string rather than an array from `recipientUser`.

To debug, I'd suggest changing your logging to:

```
if ([fetchedUserNameObject objectAtIndex:0]!= NULL)
{
   recipientUser = (User*)(fetchedUserNameObject);
   NSArray *userNames = [recipientUser valueForKey:@"username"];
   for (int i=0; i < [userNames count]; i++) {
       NSLog(@"Username %i is %@", i, [userNames objectAtIndex:i]);
   }
}
```